What type of stitch is on the interior of this hat?
I want to create a pattern for this beanie by Paa, a label which tragically ceased operations this year. They made beautifully cozy hats and I never had the chance to acquire one. I’m not an experienced knitter and I’m wondering if I could have some help identifying the stitches used and figuring out the overall construction.

It looks like the outside of the hat is tight stockinette (?) in a thick, substantial yarn with decreases (?) that almost mimic cabling.
The inside of the hat looks very unstockinette and appears to be knitted out of a different yarn, although I think the inside and outside are knitted together rather than seamed. I find this more apparent in these pictures of other colourways:


Thanks for any help you can provide.
EDIT: here is an additional picture of the join between inside and outside:


From what I can see, the outside is a simple rib pattern. You knit one, purl one, knit one, purl one, and so on. You need an even number of total stitches for this pattern. I count 38 ribs, so there are approx. 150 stitches in the round (38 ribs means only the knits stitches, so including the purls we have 76 stitches visible in half of the hat, doubling that gives us 152 stitches total). That means that a very fine yarn is used. 150 stitches is something I would expect from a hand-knit sweater pattern, not a hat.
The inside looks like sand stitch, for which you alternate knit and purl on the odd rows and knit all stitches on the even rows. This can be done with an even number of stitches (same as the outside of the hat).
Looking at the pictures, the yarn for the inside of the hat looks even finer than for the outside and the inside has even more stitches. I honestly don't think it's realistic for you to find yarn like that and recreate an exact copy (unless you own a circular knitting machine). Even if you find such fine yarn, knitting with it is not a beginner-level project. My advice is to find the softest hand-knitting yarn (but it must not be fuzzy yarn!) and adapting the pattern to your actual gauge and head size.

Thank you so much for this helpful response. Do you have insight on how the inside and outside were joined (i.e., knitted into one another or sewn)? I just received a picture of this join from a friend who has one of these hats and added it to the question; perhaps it helps. Happy to post a new question asking about the hat's structure if that's better.

It's very hard to see, but to me it looks like the stitches on the inside don't line up with those on the outside. That means it's probably 2 separate pieces, knit with different yarns and stitch counts on a (or two) circular knitting machine(s) and then sewn together. But unless you insist on a 1:1 copy, you can chose a different seam. Especially if your yarn thickness for inside and outside is identical, you'll want to have identical stitch counts, which makes it easier to just knit both pieces together.
